# Dynamic HTML Form Entry

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to make an HTML form that responds to the number of things the user wants to send over?

That is, what I have now is:

```
<form ...>
   <select ...>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      ...
   </select>
   ***
</form>
```

When the user selects one of the options, *** should have

```
<input type="text" ...>
```

appear the number of times the user selected.

That is, if the user selected 5 from the options, then the user should see 5 input options. If he changes his mind selected 2 instead, then the page should update accordingly to show only 2 input options.

**=====[EDIT]=====**

I've changed the code to have the input just be text. The code I have does not work. It doesn't update the number of input fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function updateOptions(nvars)
{
    var n = nvars;
    while(n>0) {
         var newdiv1 = "<div>Var name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"var-name\"><br></div>";
         var newdiv2 = "<div>Var type: <input type=\"text\" name=\"var-type\"><br></div>";
         newdiv1.appendTo("#bloo");
         newdiv2.appendTo("#bloo");
         n--;
    }
}
//-->
</script>

<h3>Create a table in the test db!<h3>
<form name="f1" method="POST" action="createTable.php">
        Name of Table: <input type="text" name="table-name"><br>
        No of vars: <input type="text" name="numvars" onChange="updateOptions(this.value)"><br>
        <div id="bloo"></div>
</form>
```

It worked when I had a *document.write* instead of an *appendTo*, but I essentially want the page the remain the same save for the extra input fields after the user changes the value in the *numvars* field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good idea when you want the user to be able to upload an arbitrary number of files or something like that. You can do it with Javascript:

- Have an empty DIV near the SELECT
- Bind a function to the "onchange" event on the select element
- In the function, read the value of the SELECT element and:
- - Empty the DIV
- - Create an equivalent number of <INPUT type="text"> inside the DIV

Do you need code? If you do, is Prototype OK?

---

OK, sorry for the delay, lots of work to do lately.

The following should be enough for you to get an idea. You'll have to study JS though, I don't even know what you're doing with the *appendTo* stuff in your question.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select id="num" value="1">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>

            <div id="container">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="var-name" />
                    <input type="text" name="var-type" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var selectElm = document.getElementById('num');
            var containerElm = document.getElementById('container');

            var update = function () {
                containerElm.innerHTML = '';
                for (var i = 0, l = selectElm.value; i < l; ++i) {
                    containerElm.innerHTML += '<p><input type="text" name="var-name" /><br /><input type="text" name="var-type" /></p>';
                } // add a number of couples of <input> equal to selectElm.value
            }

            //the following stuff says that when <select> changes the function called "update" must fire. Most of the code is for compatibility across browsers.
            var listen, evt;
            if (document.attachEvent) {
                listen = 'attachEvent';
                evt = 'onchange' ;
            } else {
                listen = 'addEventListener';
                evt = 'change';
            }
            try {
                selectElm[listen](evt, update);
            } catch (e) {
                selectElm[listen](evt, update, false);
            }
            // You do the same in Prototype with a single line:
            // selectElm.observe('change', update);
            // jQuery also requires only a single line of code.

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it doesn't take too much time, some code would save me a load of time.

Comment: I've just learned javascript, so I'm not sure what Prototype is.

Comment: Sorry, busy day at work, I'll see if i can write down something later.

Comment: Edited my answer with some code, I hope it will be useful to you somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes use onChange event of your dropdown input field and show/hide your input fields.